# sending data to a Server implemented in other language

Tags: python, java, network-programming, pickle, serversocket

i'm having a serializabled object from class called Account.  this object must be send from one device to other device using socket programing.  the problem is that the Server in written in Python and the Client class written in java , some people say that it is possible to write Server class in a language different from the Client class. is there any way to do that ??

```
 here is my code...
```

Client class ( Java )

```
public class CLIENT
{
           
 static Socket s;
 static OutputStream outputStream;
 static InputStream inputStream;
 
 static ObjectInputStream dis;
 static ObjectOutputStream dos;

    //  Acccunt class
    static class Account implements Serializable
    {
     String account_id = "";
     int amount = 0;
     
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int Port = 50007;              
        try
        {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", Port);
            System.out.println("Client trying to connect to port "+Port);

            OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
             
            InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
              ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
                

            System.out.println("Ready to communicate");
            while (true)
            {
           
                Account obj = new Account();
                 obj.account_id = "123";     obj.amount = 10000;

                 dos.writeObject( obj );
                 dos.flush();

                 String inn = (String) dis.readObject();     
                 System.out.println("Server: " + inn );

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {  ex.printStackTrace();  }
        
     }  // END of main
     
    }  //  End of Class
```

Server Code ( Python )

```
import socket, pickle

class Account:
    account_id = ""
    amount = 0



HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print ('Connected by', addr)

data = conn.recv(4096)
data_variable = pickle.loads(data)

print( data_variable.account_id  )
conn.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
conn.close()
```

Comment: you cant send actual objects over a socket... only bytes... but you can definitely serialize in ways that will allow you to have the data to reconstruct the object on either end  (but pickle wont work since java doesnt speak pickle as far as i know ... maybe using jython you can tweak something else on the java end to actually pass the pickle ... but i doubt its trivial)

Comment: Serialize objects into some kind of textual representation, with a well-known format and encoding, and send the text.

Comment: Use an intermediate format, such as JSON. If you've written the server yourself, then you can control what format to accept. Otherwise, look at the server's API documentation, and use one of its supported formats.

Comment: Network protocols are programming language agnostic. I does not matter which programming language, as lon as the you follow the network protocol definitions.